# How download an Excel File from SharePoint using WinForm app

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, sharepoint

I have the following path in the SharePoint:

http://xxxx.xxx.com/bu/PSCLA/Document_3/LA%20Sites/Rio/Site%20OP%20Strategy/Master%20Data%20Audit%20Hair%20Care%20Rio%20Plant/MRP%201-4%20and%20WS%20POSS.xlsx

I need download and store this file in my personal computer using a WinForm application created in VS 2013, Framework .Net 4.0.

Exists some method to achieve this with only the direct link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to asynchronously download, use this:

```
private void buttonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
  webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadFileProgressChanged);
  webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/myfile.xlsx"), @"c:\myfile.xlsx");
}

private void DownloadFileProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Update the progress bar component
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```